# vim: how to duplicate one record

Tags: vim, macros

I have more than 40000 records like this:

```
------
18
1,5,0.33
6,10,0.34
11,15,0.36
16,20,0.37
21,25,0.40
26,30,0.44
------
```

And I want to transform like that:

```
------
18 1,5,0.33
18 6,10,0.34
18 11,15,0.36
18 16,20,0.37
18 21,25,0.40
18 26,30,0.44
------
```

Knowing that:

- The number of lines after the first number is variable but *always > 1*
- I know about recording macros, so I want to record one and play it 40000 times. I just want to know from a user point of view which keys I have to type

Comment: What have you tried? How would you manually attack that problem? With that, you're almost there; it's just a small step to a reliable macro.

Comment: I just didn't know how to paste via `<c-r>` (is `Ctrl+r`) like LK explained in his answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following sequence should do the trick

```
dd<cr>
:%norm I<c-r>*<bck> <cr>
```

where `<cr>` is carriage return and `<c-r>` is Ctrl+r

Breakdown is as follows

- `dd` deletes the first line containing the character you'd like to insert
- `:%norm` executes a normal command on the rest of the file
- `I` takes care of inserting in front of the line.
- `<c-r>*` pastes the deleted first line content including the newline.
- `<bck> <cr>` to clean up the newline and add a space

---

If you want to type it then:

- <kbd>Down</kbd>`vey`<kbd>Down</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`v`
- `/^-`<kbd>Up</kbd>
- `I`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`r*`<kbd>Backspace</kbd>

Explanation:

- Go to first number: <kbd>Down</kbd>, `v`: select mode; `e` go to the end of the word
- Copy: `y`
- Visual mode blockwise: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`v`
- Search for first line beginning with `-` then <kbd>Up</kbd>: `/^-`<kbd>Up</kbd>
- Insert mode that copies to all lines and paste current buffer: `I`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`r*`

Answer (score 1):

another option:

```
DJ
:%s/^/<c-r>" /
```

Comment: +1 Ah, that answers my question about the `dd`including the newline. tx

Comment: I've edited LK's answer to add my solution I've just applied to the records. Thank you for your solution!

Comment: @OlivierPons - the `dd` in my response kan be replaced by `DJ` so you don't need the backspace.

Comment: Is there a way to add it not at the beginning, but at the end of all selected lines, *whatever the length of the line is*?

Comment: Replace the `I` with `A` in my answer or replace `^` with `$` in this answer.